# Excel doesn't want to see all rows same time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I created an Excel file that includes 10,000 rows. Some of my columns have formulas.

I am sharing this workbook with 3 friends. Everybody is filling cells, but now we are at 588 rows. When I tried scrolling down, Excel scrolls 500 rows each time. This makes finding some rows near impossible for us.

Are there any options for blocking viewed data each time? For example, just show 100 rows? <s>When I came last row add 100 more rows.</s>

Comment: You didn't explain your problem clearly unfortunately.  If you can show us some data, it would go a really long way here.

Comment: Nope, you did not explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Use autofilter to search the data?

Comment: You could try hiding certain rows, or set the ScrollArea of the sheet to ignore the first whatever rows. Or use autofilter as already stated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, all you have to do is highlight all rows you don't want to see, right click on the selection, and click on "Hide".

Answer (score 0):

May be using code in selection change event

```html
        Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                    .Goto Cells(Target.Row, 1), True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End Sub
```